# How to Specify single quote in regular expression

Tags: regex

Here is my regular expression . I want to include single quotes (') within the characters such as (O'Neal Nickel). Here is my regular expression allowing letters and spaces and full stops(.) and (-) hyphens

```
 /^[A-Za-z\/\s\.-]+$/;
```

Comment: `/^[A-Za-z\/\s\.'-]+$/;`

Comment: Please don’t encourage people to escape things they don’t need to.

Comment: @tchrist Hmmm, I just copy and pasted the regex and added a `'`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`/^[A-Za-z\/\s\.'-]+$/;`
Or did I get your question wrong?

Comment: If that's the answer can you explain it a bit?

Comment: I just added the single quote. You don't have to escape it. You only have to add it to the list of allowed characters []

Comment: @Urasquirrel - you can contact me via twitter and I guess I can explain it better in a chat...

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
/^[A-Za-z\/\s\.'\-]+$/;
```

You do not need to backslash/escape the single quote. Doing so will cause Safari to disallow single quote marks instead of allowing them.

Comment: No, you don't need to backslash it.

Comment: ah okay, didn't know that... I'm escaping it anyways could be a bad habit. peace

Answer (score 4):

`/^[A-Za-z\/\s\.'-]+$/`

@Urasquirrel - you asked for **detailed** explanation and I know that whenever I see questions like this, I want the same thing!!

```
^ - beginning of the string 
[ - allowed characters are contained in the square brackets
A-Z - uppercase A to Z
a-z - lowercase a to z
\/ - escaped forward slash
\s - whitespace
\. - escaped period
' - single quote
- - a dash
] - end of square brackets
+ - ONE of more of the allowed characters contained in the square brackets
$ - end of string
```

https://regex101.com/ is a great place to test different RE patterns with different strings and different languages. there are other sites that do similar

Answer (score 0):

```
var testName=/^[A-Za-z\/\s\.'-]+$/;
var name= $("#name").val();
if(testName.test(name) == false || name == "")
{}
```

This is a code I used to check name