# How to add single quote regex pattern in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, regex

Can anybody tell me how to allow **single quote, A-Z, one space, and a .dot** in regular expression language.  I am  using is VB.NET.

Comment: WHat are you trying to accomplish?? AN example would be better??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the escape character "\" in regex. For example `\.` will match the dot itself instead of any character.

Single quote you can refer to [How to Specify single quote in regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392388/how-to-specify-single-quote-in-regular-expression)

Answer (score 0):

If it is just one character you want to check, use the regex `[A-Z\. ']`:

```
Dim myRegex As New Regex("[A-Z\. ']")
```

If you want to check a string that must not have other characters, use

```
Dim myRegex As New Regex("^[A-Z\. ']*$")
```